# when to use service for MediaPlayerin android studio

Tags: android, encryption, android-mediaplayer, background-service

In my app, I downloaded the audio from the server and then played, but the MediaPlayer was stopped by locking my cellphone, so I added a background service for playing. after that, I changed my mind and I wanted users can't access my audios, so I've encrypted audios and decrypted to play. By this way, I didn't need the background service.
I am totally confused. I don't need the service because of saving on internal!!!!!
Can you explain it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean internal storage byandroid.content.Context.getDir(String name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE):

Comment: and also in my app users can record their voices, and they're saved in local database (I mean External Storage by android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()). that audios don't need background service for running again.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what type of application you are developing. If this is a music player where user should be able to listen even if app is closed, then use a service. Audios are merely files, if they are encrypted just decrypt them before playing. 
On the other hand if your application is some sort of an audio editor where user should actively use app while playing with audio, then you may not use a service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i didn't get, my app has different behavior, when I download audio file from server and save on external storage, I need service, but when I record audio and save on external storage I don't need service,why? for both of them I just read from external without encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: When you are downloading a file from the server you need to use an `IntentService` because you're performing work in the background. Most people choose to implement it using 3rd party libraries such as Retrofit or Fetch.

Comment: I use volley library and I put my download codes  in a class that  extends AsyncTask, and I play the audio in onPostExecute. I need service to play that audio saving on external storage.